# VBA looping, remove password, same data being re-saved to each file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, passwords

Thanks to some great help on here, I used the below VBA code to loop through a directory of xlsx files and remove the known password (same for each).  However, suddenly, this code below is taking the contents of the first file and saving it to the other files.  While it is removing the password, all files in the folder end up having their contents replaced by the contents of the first workbook whose password is removed using the code below.  The password is being removed, no problem there, but the contents of each file is simply being overwritten by the contents of the first file that is opened.

```
Public Sub RemovePassLoopThroughFiles()
    
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim folderWildcard As String
    Dim currentFileName As String
    Dim currentFileExtension As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim newfileNameSuffix As String
    Dim currentPassword As String
    Dim newPassword As String
    
    ' Adjust next lines to fit your needs
    
    folderPath = "C:\Temp\" ' With slash at the end
    folderWildcard = "*.xls*" ' You can change the suffix to open specific files
    
    newfileNameSuffix = "_NoPassword"
    
    currentPassword = "pw"
    newPassword = ""
    
    ' Get the file path concat folder and wildcards
    filePath = Dir(folderPath & folderWildcard)
      
    
    Do While Len(filePath) > 0
        ' Open the workbook and set reference
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:=currentPassword)
        
        ' Get current file extension
        currentFileExtension = Right(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "."))
        
        ' Get filename no extension
        currentFileName = Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Build new fileName
        newFileName = currentFileName & newfileNameSuffix & "." & currentFileExtension
        
        ' Set new password
        targetWorkbook.Password = newPassword
        
        ' Save new file
        targetWorkbook.SaveAs folderPath & newFileName

        'Debug.Print filePath
        
        filePath = Dir

        targetWorkbook.Close True
        
        Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
        
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks good to me, what versions of Excel?

Comment: @Profex I am using Excel 2016 on Windows.

Comment: my only thought is that maybe `targetWorkbook` doesn't point to the savedAs version of the workbook, and so it never gets closed?

Comment: @ArcherBird So if I adjust the code to just overwrite the current file once the password is removed, that might prevent the content of that first file from being saved into the subsequent files in the folder?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print targetWorkbook.FullName` before and after the `SaveAs`

Comment: @Profex. That Debug line throws an error, the first one.  Never makes it past that.

Comment: @JohnTaylor, Check again, I changed it.  Also, the issue is that you're not including the path.  You should use `Workbooks.Open(Filename:=folderPath & filePath)`

Comment: @Profex What was the change, just that line above with the Filename:=folderPath & filePath?  I had that originally, but it kept throwing an error there as well.  I will put it back.  What other change did you make?

Comment: `Debug.Print targetWorkbook.FullFileName` -> `Debug.Print targetWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: @Profex I am going to run that again shortly and comment here with the results.  Thanks so much for helping me work through this.  I am not new to programming, but definitely new to VBA so it's been an adjustment.

Comment: @JohnTaylor, good news is that you can always put a break in the code using `F9`, Mouse over any variable to see the value, or use Watch/Locals.  You can even move the Yellow cursor, to rerun lines again and again.  Before you pick up too many bad habits, see [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Comment: Because you are saving the NoPassword files into the same folder as the original files, check that you are not reprocessing the NoPassword files. The giveaway would be if you started with a file called "foo.xlsx" and ended up with "foo_NoPassword.xlsx" and "foo_NoPassword_NoPassword.xlsx" and so on